# Finding inverse of Elementary matrices

Tags: matrices

I wish to prove that for an identity matrix I of order n , n is a + ve integer, inverse of a matrix A = [a_ij] obtained by interchanging any two rows / columns of identity matrix I is again the same matrix A.
i.e. Inv( E_ij)= E_ij , 1<= i,j<=n 
where E_ij is elementary matrix obtained by interchanging R_i with R_j or by interchanging C_i withC_j.

What I have done so far?
I got that det(E_ij) = -1 as interchanging any two rows / columns only changes the sign of a determinant. 
I tried finding out adj( E_ij)
,but unable to calculate cofactors of two elements a_ij and a_ji ,both of which are unity. Any help to find adj(E_ij).

Comment: What does the identity matrix $I$ have to do with the inverse of $A$, or $E$. Can you please give a simple example with $n=3$ in order to understand what the thought process is here.

Comment: Sir, A or E_ij is the matrix obtained from Identity matrix I by interchanging i'th and j 'th rows of I

Comment: So like $$ \begin{bmatrix} &  & 1\\
1\\
 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} & 1\\
 &  & 1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\
 & 1\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix} $$ ?